# Git bash how to exit from read mode?

Tags: windows-7, git-bash

For example I type `git diff commit1 cimmit2` and start read changes by scroll with down arrow and after I saw what I want I use `CTRL+C` for exit but when I start typing something I return to reading that diff which I thought that I  close with `CTRL+C`. How to properly interrupt read mode?

**UPD:** Found Answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929457/how-do-i-exit-the-results-of-git-diff-in-git-bash-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

you can use q or Q followed by ^M (or ascii control M) and NOT ENTER key; otherwise you have to change core configuration for crlf mapping to lf that could block adding file to tracking